# Improper integral question involing divergence

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\log^n(x)} \,dx$ diverges for all real numbers $n$.

I have gotten the value of the integral, which is $\frac{1}{n}(\log(\log x)) + C$. However, I am having trouble proving that this integral diverges. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hint: compute $lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) - lim_{x \to 1} F(x)$, where $F(x)$ is the primitive. What do you get?

Comment: I get that the first one is infinite and the other is negatively infinite.

Comment: $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate form, so the integral is not well-defined.

Comment: Isn't it $\infty - (-\infty)$?